# How can I select the Text Annotation tool through python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, annotation

Some of the QGIS tools can be selected/activated via PyQGIS using the `iface` object (see [QgisInterface](http://www.qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgisInterface.html)). For example:

```
iface.actionIdentify().trigger() # Activates the Identify tool
```

However, the Text Annotation tool (and also HTML, SVG, and Form annotation tools) are not available in `iface`.

How can I select/activate the Text Annotation tool from my QGIS python plugin?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no direct method to select the QGIS Text Annotation tool from the `iface` object, you can do it in this way:

For QGIS 2.x

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction
iface.mainWindow().findChild( QAction, 'mActionTextAnnotation' ).trigger()
```

Updated for QGIS 3.x

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction

iface.mainWindow().findChild( QAction, 'mActionHtmlAnnotation' ).trigger()
```

You can use the others related actions e.g `mActionFormAnnotation`, `mActionHtmlAnnotation`, `mActionSvgAnnotation` instead of `mActionTextAnnotation`

Comment: It worked!, that worked perfectly.